# Update Magento basket on pre-selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have two delivery options on the checkout of my Magento site. By default I have the free delivery selected. I am using this code:

```
(function($) {
  $('#checkout-shipping-method-load .input-checkout-radio .method-title:contains(Take it to my room)', function() {
    $("#s_method_premium").prop("checked", true);
    if (!window.location.hash) {
      window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

to select the paid delivery. The issue I face here is how do I update the basket values to reflect the 39 pounds charge?